# choppy scrolling in IE7

Tags: html, css, scroll

I've built a website for someone, but according to him, scrolling is very very choppy on the website in IE7 on his computer. On my computer I don't have any problems with scrolling (in any browser), i've already tried some things, but according to him scrolling still is very choppy. So I was wondering if someone has some suggestions for me? I think the main problem is the full width background image, but i'm not entirely sure.
The website is:
[www.casalagodilugano.nl](http://www.casalagodilugano.nl)
The website is in dutch, but for this question that doesn't have to matter

edit:
Tx for the helpful answers. In the end, it was indeed the background image which caused problems in IE7. By accident I found a way to work around this problem: I set the image as the background image, centered the image, and using css3 I made sure the was stretched the way it should.

Comment: Link? Code? Difficult to help without.

Comment: IE7 is a slow browser. No surprise there.

Comment: could be a display driver issue :) disabled video hardware acceleration perhaps.

Comment: Link is provided in my question: <www.casalagodilugano.nl>

Code is to long to post here, but of course you'll all know how to get that from the website.


@Spudley @Salman A: I know IE7 is slow, and I know it's probably his computer, but that doesn't change the fact that some computers (many computers since IE is still used by 50% of the people) will have this problem on this website, and I need to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a problem similar to this. It turned out to be because my computer was full and my performance suffered. Viewing the issue on my new machine (also had IE7) produced no choppy scrolling. I fear your client has the same problem, perhaps suggest it's his computer and not your website?

**Edit:**

Many things affect the processing on a website, I'd suggest it has to do with your background image. The sand has quite a "repeatable" texture so perhaps you should Photoshop it down so it's a much smaller image and just use 'background-repeat' in your CSS to achieve a similar effect. Your background image is also around 200% of what it displays on the website, I copied the URL of the image and viewed it by itself and it's HUGE! The emphasis here is on image file size, because IE is having trouble shifting the image down when you scroll. It's not a very good browser to be fair. I've also noticed that your large header image is larger in actual size, suggesting that the size is reduced by your code. Try reducing this image size to the size you want to display it

**Edit pt 2**

I've stumbled upon a script that for some reason waits 5 seconds before running and that is the Google maps API. I respect that you need this for the Routes page but if I were you, on any page where there is no map, remove any mention of the google maps api from the source code.

Comment: the thing is, I know it is probably his computer. But if he has choppy scrolling, than possible visitors can also have choppy scrolling. Moreover, he doesn't has this problem on most other websites (usually without a fullwidth background), so to him it's the problem of the website, not of his computer.

Comment: I've edited the post with some additional information for you

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've considered the background-repeat to, but the main problem is the italian flag. Because this is not a straight line, I can't use background-repeat on that. And if i'm correct it's faster to have just one big background image, than one repeated image, with an transparent image on top of that. But I'll try to reduce the size of the pictures.

Comment: It may also do you justice to connect to an "off-site" version of JQuery instead of the downloaded package https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1):

I have found that IE gets choppy when you have an <input> tag without a border or background specified ... very strange IE "bug" but i've fixed choppy scrolling on  sites/pages by just adding a border to the <input> tags.